# RabbitMQ: Multiple listeners of a single queue and prevent concurrency on a message property

Tags: concurrency, rabbitmq

I am evaluating RabbitMQ and would like to do the following:

- Put messages in a single queue with an integer property X with a range of 4 million.
- Multiple messages with the same value of X will be present in the queue.
- Read the queue with multiple listeners but make sure that none of the listeners are processing a message with the same value of X concurrently.

Is this possible with RabbitMQ and which feature should I use?

EDIT

We changed to ActiveMQ which has this feature

Comment: Have you found answer?

Comment: No. We will probably write something ourself to fix this issue. No queueing system is able to do what we want

Comment: Queues with multiple listeners sounds a lot like topics.